# Prevent RewriteRule to influence loading scripts and stylesheets

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

.htaccess file :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,QSA,L]    # <= This is the problem
```

HTML Head :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="./scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/styles.css">
</head>
[...]
```

It seems that the RewriteRule prevents all local scripts and stylesheets from loading...

How can I solve that problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with your RewriteRule, you rewrite all files, even ./*.js and ./*.css files.

You should add RewriteCond this to try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,QSA,L]    # <= This is the problem
```

Thus apache rewrites nonexistent files such as foo, bar, ... to index.php.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However after trying, I have now an AJAX error (after $.post, there's a SyntaxError)... I'll keep on investigating just to see how this can be.

Comment: Just to be clear : commenting the rewrite makes the error disappear.

Comment: You should check direct URL browsing to test if rewriting works. jQuery might be another problem. SyntaxError is it at JavaScript level ?

Comment: Just finished testing and solved the issue. Long story short : a misconfig in another file led to the error I got by using the rewrite function. Clearly your answer @jacouh solved my initial problem. I'll mark your answer as accepted and I thank you for your help !